# FormClosing Treatment ErrorProvider

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, errorprovider

I ran into a problem closing a form where my ErrorProvider wouldn't let me do it.
To correct it I made a jerry-rigged creating a variable Boolena to confirm if the form was being closed.
I had already tried FormClosing but still the ErrorProvider was validating the focus field.
Has anyone had the same problem? How did you solve it?
I wanted to do it more elegantly.

**Form Initialize**

```
public partial class MyForm: form
{
  private bool _isClosing = false;
...
...
}
```

**Generic Validate With Error Provider**

```
private bool ValidatingFields(Control control)
{
  bool eventArgs = false;
  if (!this._isClosing) //Boolean Variable jerry-rigged
  {
    
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
    {
      eventArgs = true;
      control.BackColor = Color.Red;
      errorProvider.SetError(control, "Campo Obrigatório!");
    }
    else
    {
      eventArgs = false;
      errorProvider.SetError(control, null);
    }
 }
 return eventArgs;
}
```

**Field Validating**

```
private void textName_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  e.Cancel = ValidatingFields(textName);
}
```

**Event Close Button Click**

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this._isClosing = true;
  this.Close();
}
```

Comment: One of the reasons to use an ErrorProvider, is to avoid the Validating event and its `e.Cancel` property. You can use other events to validate the input, as the `Leave` event. Then, only when a User clicks the confirmation Button (`OK`, `Apply`), execute the test to decide whether to perform any action related to the input. Hence a User can close a Form using the Window's Close Button or a Cancel Button without being harassed for no good reason (since they're just canceling the operation in any case), so no input needs to be processed.

Comment: ty. I Will do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah Nothing wrong in this behavior. Control Validation will trigger any button click event except who's **CausesValidation = False**. In short you can set this property of the cancel button to "False". This will skip the validation.